# Doing data subsetting on condition of the loop index in SAS

Tags: sas

```
data test1;
   do i=0 to 10 by 0.1;
   j=i*10;
   output;
   end;
run;

data test2;
   set test1;
   if i=3;
run;
```

If I run this code, there will be no record in test2, why this is happening? "i" ranges from 0 to 10 increased by 0.1 for each record, why I cannot select the one with i=3. And what's more, if I use the condition "i<=3", the records with i=0 to 2.9 will be selected.

Any one know the reason?

Comment: The reason is the same as the problem in the linked question - if you have further specific questions, please ask them (separately) or ask in comments here if you don't completely understand the connection.

Comment: after rounding, to 1 decimal place, I can select the value I want now. But I am still confuse, `i` was defined as a numeric variable with 1 decimal place (because it increases by 0.1 each time) in a best12. format. Why SAS cannot find the corresponding record even when I use, for example,  `i=2.9`?

Comment: Reread the answer on the other question again, then.  SAS has only floating point numbers, so there is no concept of 'only one decimal place' for a number stored as numeric.

Comment: thanks, I think I understand now. BTW, correct me if I'm wrong, in this situation, i and j are stored in SAS as float number (as contrast to integer), the value shows `3` is actually not 3, it's something like 3.00000000000001. And when we are writing conditions on float numbers, we should always round them?

Comment: Yes, exactly the case.